# Process exits immediately after process.Start() only with arguments

Tags: c#, process

Here's my code:

```
Process process = GetServerProcess();

if (process != null) return;

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = PROCESS_PATH;
processStartInfo.Arguments = "7777";

process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

The main problem is that WITH arguments process starts and immediately closes, but WITHOUT arguments it start perfect and don't closes

I tried different process to start and all of them exits if i start them with arguments.

*Sorry for my English, it'n not my native language. Trying to write correct*

Comment: Depends entirely on the actual process and how it behaves when being called with or without parameters.

Comment: I would try to run the command manually in commandline. If the result is the same there is problem with the process you called, if it works differently than maybe your process building code structure is not well structured.

Comment: If i make a link with parameters and run manually this link, app starts without any problems. But I dont know why process can't be started well when I'm use Process.Start() with parameters

Comment: Try redirecting the error output to see if the process tells you why it failed.

Comment: When I use redirecting, I have to UseShellExecute = false. When I use UseShellExecute = false, ErrorStream is empty. When I use UseHellExecute = false without parameters, then process only show black console window and nothing is going on